# Comparing two nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, dictionary

I have two nested dictionaries which I want to compare Dictionary d1 has desired values that I am pulling from my yaml file and d2 has  Current values that I am getting from aws security group. I want to compare two dict and display

Scenario 1
unexpected values which are there in d2 but not in d1

Scenario 2
and also display values which are there in d1 but were not in d2.

I have the following code as of now

```
def CompareDict(d1, d2, ctx=""):
    for k in d2:
        if k not in d1:
            continue
        if d2[k] != d1[k]:
            if type(d2[k]) not in (dict, list):
                print k +" Expected Value "+str(d1[k])+" but found "+str(d2[k])
            else:
                if type(d1[k]) != type(d2[k]):
                    continue
                else:
                    if type(d2[k]) == dict:
                        CompareDict(d1[k], d2[k], k)
                        continue
                    elif type(d2[k]) == list:
                        CompareDict(list_to_dict(d1[k]), list_to_dict(d2[k]), k)
    return
```

This works fine for the below scenario when my two dictionary are -

D2

```
{u'SecurityGroups': [{u'IpPermissions': [{u'ToPort': 99, u'FromPort': 0, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': '104.129.192.69/32'}], u'IpProtocol': 'udp'}], u'IpPermissionsEgress': [{u'ToPort': 1, u'FromPort': 0, u'IpRanges': [], u'IpProtocol': 'tcp'}]}]}
```

D1

```
{u'SecurityGroups': [{u'IpPermissions': [{u'ToPort': 89, u'FromPort': 80, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/1'}], u'IpProtocol': u'tcp'}], u'IpPermissionsEgress': [{u'ToPort': 1, u'FromPort': 0, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/32'}], u'IpProtocol': u'tcp'}]}]}
```

Output

> ToPort Expected Value 89 but found 99
>
> FromPort Expected Value 80 but found 0
>
> CidrIp Expected Value 0.0.0.0/1 but found 104.129.192.69/32
>
> IpProtocol Expected Value tcp but found udp

But fails to check for scenario 2 when I have two dict as

--D2----

```
{u'SecurityGroups': [{u'IpPermissions': [{u'ToPort': 89, u'FromPort': 80, u'IpRanges': [], u'IpProtocol': 'tcp'}], u'IpPermissionsEgress': [{u'ToPort': 1, u'FromPort': 0, u'IpRanges': [], u'IpProtocol': 'tcp'}]}]}
```

—D1———

```
{u'SecurityGroups': [{u'IpPermissions': [{u'ToPort': 89, u'FromPort': 80, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/1'}], u'IpProtocol': u'tcp'}], u'IpPermissionsEgress': [{u'ToPort': 1, u'FromPort': 0, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/0'}], u'IpProtocol': u'tcp'}]}]}
```

Output

> None

Can somebody please help. I am new to python would really appreciate any help

UPDATED -

Scenario 3 (fails to detect change in cidrIp value as it is '0.0.0.0/0' in D2 and ‘0.0.0.0/1’ in D1.)

D2

```
{u'SecurityGroups': [{u'IpPermissions': [{u'ToPort': 89, u'FromPort': 80, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], u'IpProtocol': 'tcp'}], u'IpPermissionsEgress': [{u'ToPort': 1, u'FromPort': 0, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/32'}], u'IpProtocol': 'tcp'}]}]}
```

D1

```
{u'SecurityGroups': [{u'IpPermissions': [{u'ToPort': 89, u'FromPort': 80, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/1'}], u'IpProtocol': u'tcp'}], u'IpPermissionsEgress': [{u'ToPort': 1, u'FromPort': 0, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/32'}], u'IpProtocol': u'tcp'}]}]}
```

> Output :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will meet everything you need.

```
import json
def compareIterables(d1, d2):
    if [type(d1), type(d2)] == [dict,dict]:
        notInD2 = set(d1.keys()) - set(d2.keys())
        notInD1 = set(d2.keys()) - set(d1.keys())
        inBoth  = set(d2.keys()) & set(d1.keys())
        for key in notInD2:
            print "D2[{}] is not defined. Value in D1: {}".format(key, json,dumps(D1[key]))
        for key in notInD1:
            print "D1[{}] is not defined. Value in D2: {}".format(key, json,dumps(D2[key]))
    elif [type(d1), type(d2)] == [list,list]:
        len1 = len(d1)
        len2 = len(d2)
        if(len(d1) != len(d2)):
            print "lists {} and {} do not have the same length!".format(d1,d2)
            return
        else:
            inBoth = range(0,len1) 
    for key in inBoth:
        if all([x not in [dict,list] for x in [type(d1[key]),type(d2[key])]]):
            if type(d1[key]) == type(d2[key]):
                if d1[key] != d2[key]:
                    print "d1[{0}] ({1}) does not match d2[{0}] ({2})".format(key, d1[key], d2[key])
        else:
            if([type(d1[key]),type(d2[key])] == [list,list]):
                compareIterables(d1[key],d2[key])
            elif([type(d1[key]),type(d2[key])] == [dict,dict]):
                compareIterables(d1[key],d2[key])
            elif type(d1[key]) != type(d2[key]):
                print "type of d1[{0}] ({1}) does not match d2[{0}] ({2})".format(key, type(d1[key]), type(d2[key]))
```

This outputs for the second pair of dictionaries your provided.

```
lists [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/1'}] and [] do not have the same length!
lists [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/0'}] and [] do not have the same length!
```

You can modify this script to recursively pass a key for better identification or any other features you need. This is just a baseline.

Comment: Thank you so much jay for your help. The Code does work for scenario 2 but I checked for couple of cases like Scenario 3 (Updated in question) it fails to detect change in cidrIp value as it is '0.0.0.0/0' in D2 and ‘0.0.0.0/1’ in D1. I think that is because we are checking the length instead of the value itself? Can you please help

Comment: @AjayMisra no the problem in this case is the type. Before comparing two values, I am checking `if type(d1[key]) == type(d2[key]):` In your updated question, d1's `CidrIp` is `unicode` type (which is the `u` infront of the string), whereas d2's `CidrIp` is a regular `str` type. I dont know what is causing this difference on your side. It's up to you if you want to keep that condition or not. Alternatively, you could cast all your unicode strings to regular strings using the `str` function, if you are sure that there will be no special unicode characters in your data.

Comment: Thank you so much that really helped. You are awesome. I will be working more on python in coming weeks hope to see you more on Stackoverflow :)